# Customizing the jQuery-File-Upload (Basic Plugin)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-file-upload

I came across [jQuery-file-upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) in a google search. I found it neat and exactly what I need but I'm having a small issue getting just a couple features the way I want it to work using the basic plugin. I figure the basic-plugin would be the best to shape and mold into exactly what I wanted. This is what I have so far.

### app.js

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '../php/',
        add: function (e, data) {
            //$.each(data.files, function(index, file) {
                data.context = $('<li class=\"list-group-item\">')
                    //.html(file.name+"<button type=\"button\" id=\"drop\" class=\"btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></span></button>")
                    // see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234279/blueimp-jquery-upload-multiple-files-doesnt-work for the reason for the line below
                    .html(data.files[0].name+"<button type=\"button\" id=\"drop\" class=\"btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></span></button>")
                    .appendTo(".list-group");
                /*$('.btn-danger').on('click', function() {
                    console.log('Drop '+file.name+' \n');
                });*/
            //});
            $('.btn-danger').on('click', function() {
                console.log("Removing all objects...\n");
                data.context.remove();
            });


        },
        submit: function (e, data) {
            $('#start-upload').on('click', function() {
                //$('#start-upload').addClass('#disabledInput');
                console.log("This is the start upload button!");
            });
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            /*$.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('.files').find('#panel-body');
            });*/
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        },
        drop: function (e, data) {
            //$.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                //$('#btn-danger').on('click', function() {
                    console.log('Dropped file: '+ file.name +'\n');
                //});
            //});
        }
    }).on('fileuploadsubmit', function(e, data) {
        data.formData = data.context.find(':input').seralizeArray();
    });
});
```

### ../php/index.php

```
<?php
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin PHP Example 5.14
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

$options = array(
    'delete_type' => 'POST',
    'db_host' => 'localhost',
    'db_user' => 'root',
    'db_pass' => '',
    'db_name' => 'example',
    'db_table' => 'files'
);

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');

class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler {

    protected function initialize() {
        $this->db = new mysqli(
            $this->options['db_host'],
            $this->options['db_user'],
            $this->options['db_pass'],
            $this->options['db_name']
        );
        parent::initialize();
        $this->db->close();
    }

    protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
        $file->title = @$_REQUEST['title'][$index];
        $file->description = @$_REQUEST['description'][$index];
    }

    protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
            $index = null, $content_range = null) {
        $file = parent::handle_file_upload(
            $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range
        );
        if (empty($file->error)) {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
                .'` (`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `description`)'
                .' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param(
                'sisss',
                $file->name,
                $file->size,
                $file->type,
                $file->title,
                $file->description
            );
            $query->execute();
            $file->id = $this->db->insert_id;
        }
        return $file;
    }

    protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
        parent::set_additional_file_properties($file);
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
            $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `type`, `title`, `description` FROM `'
                .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=?';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param('s', $file->name);
            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result(
                $id,
                $type,
                $title,
                $description
            );
            while ($query->fetch()) {
                $file->id = $id;
                $file->type = $type;
                $file->title = $title;
                $file->description = $description;
            }
        }
    }

    public function delete($print_response = true) {
        $response = parent::delete(false);
        foreach ($response as $name => $deleted) {
            if ($deleted) {
                $sql = 'DELETE FROM `'
                    .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=?';
                $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $query->bind_param('s', $name);
                $query->execute();
            }
        } 
        return $this->generate_response($response, $print_response);
    }

}

$upload_handler = new CustomUploadHandler($options);

?>
```

[image: Basic layout of my buttons and file list.]

In my html I also have a Select Files... button, and a Start Upload button. The 'Select Files' button works perfectly. I can add files without a problem. Multiple at once, or one at a time.

The two features I need help with the most are linking a "remove" button to each `<li>` element that belongs to each file that has been selected, and then simply implementing the Start Upload button that will upload the files. I will use the example php to processing the files.

**How can I go about implementing the "remove button" of each `<li>` button?**
What I've done so far:

- Add the "remove" button to each list element
- Implement a way for the user to click the remove button and the filename for the clicked `li` element is logged to console. However, this log is repeated x many times where x is the position of the `li` element relative to the top.

**How can I implement the "start upload" button to begin the upload?**
I'm not absolutely sure how the `php` file is tied into the jQuery so that it executes when the submit button is pressed. I know the `.on` action is attached to the `.fileupload` but if someone could help explain how everything comes together it'd be very appreciated.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You need a server side script/application to do what you want. The areas for the upload you have are for that purpose. JavaScript is only on the client side. I saw php as a tag which makes me think that's okay. So post what your php for this looks like and I can tell you how to call the upload.  Not sure how to do the remove.

Comment: I've added .php and edited my .js files to more accurately describe my current situation.